# Exponential Growth calculator?

Tags: javascript

This simple javascript/html combination that should calculate exponential growth is not working for me
It returns NaN when I submit

This is the code:

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function Start() {
var GetA = document.getElementById("A").value;
var GetB = document.getElementById("B").value;
var GetX = document.getElementById("X").value;
var ParseA = parseInt(GetA);
var ParseB = parseInt(GetB);
var ParseX = parseInt(GetX);
var Num1 = ParseB + 100;
var Num2 = Num1 * .01;
var Num3 = Math.pow(Num2, ParseA);
var Num4 = Num3 * ParseA;
document.getElementById("Answer").innerHTML = Num4;
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<input id="A" placeholder="Starting Number">
<br />
<input id="B" placeholder="Rate">
<br />
<input id="X" placeholder="Time">
<br />
<input type="button" id="Submit" value="Submit" onclick="Start()">
<p id="Answer"></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators#Bitwise_operators. The `^` operator isn't what you're looking for.

Comment: The problem is you are getting the values before they are entered and `parseInt("")` returns `NaN`. Every math operation involving NaN propagates the NaN.

Comment: [Learn how to debug JavaScript](http://www.creativebloq.com/javascript/javascript-debugging-beginners-3122820). Look at the console. Notice the error? Solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14028959/why-does-jquery-or-a-dom-method-such-as-getelementbyid-not-find-the-element

Comment: Don't edit your code with the suggestions you get in the answers. Because the answers won't make sense anymore. Or did you really use `Math.pow` instead of `^`?

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> var Num3 = Num2 ^ ParseA;
> ```

`^` is the [bitwise xor operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators). You probably want to use [`Math.pow(Num2, ParseA)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/pow) instead.

> It returns NaN when I submit

Only the `Start` function is executed when you submit. The `Parse[ABX]` variables however are initialized when the document loads - and will have the value `undefined`, which leads to `NaN` in calculations.

Move the part where you're getting the values from the inputs in the function.

Comment: True, but this isn't causing the issue of NaN.

Comment: Don't you mean `Math.pow`?

Comment: Used, it still getting NaN

Comment: @FelixKling: `Math.exp(ParseA*Math.log(Num2))` - umm, of course `pow`. And I'm going to bed now.

Answer (score 2):

The problem with the `NaN`<sup>1</sup> is the code is trying to access the DOM elements *before* they are added to the DOM and the variables are ending up with garbage values.

This is actually causing an Exception - as `getElementById(..)` returns null and `null.value` is invalid - and the script execution is aborted. The error console will contain a message similar to "TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null" . Due to "hoisting" of Function Declaration, the Start function is still defined.

Because of this error, the values ParseA/B/X are `undefined`. This causes certain math operations, such as `undefined + number` (as in `ParseB + 100`) to return `NaN`. Every subsequent math operation (e.g. `Num1 * .01`) involving the introduced NaN propagates the NaN.

Instead, wait to access the values until `Start`: after the elements exist (so that there is no exception) and valid values have been entered (so that parseInt itself won't return NaN).

*If the following code still results in "NaN" output, then `NaN` was introduced in one of the `parseInt` lines*.

```
function Start() {
    var GetA = document.getElementById("A").value;
    var ParseA = parseInt(GetA, 10);
    var GetB = document.getElementById("B").value;
    var ParseB = parseInt(GetB, 10);
    var GetX = document.getElementById("X").value;
    var ParseX = parseInt(GetX, 10);

    var Num1 = ParseB + 100;
    var Num2 = Num1 * .01;
    var Num3 = Num2 ^ ParseA;
    var Num4 = Num3 * ParseA;
    document.getElementById("Answer").innerHTML = Num4;
}
```

Note that I also specified a radix (10), which is good practice for `parseInt`.

---

<sup>1</sup> The incorrect usage of `^` is a problem as discussed in Bergi's answer, would would result in an incorrect answer, but not `NaN` unless it is propagated from elsewhere.

Comment: *"you are trying to read the input values before they are entered"* That as well, but he even tries to access the DOM elements before they exist.

Comment: Still NaN after I fixed that

Comment: @user3247345 Step it with a debugger and inspect the values.

Comment: @FelixKling Thanks. Reworked the answer to explain the situation correctly (this time).